# Error bars in repeated k-fold cross-validation

Tags: variance, cross-validation, error

Suppose I want to compute the expectation of the loss $L$ based on Repeated K-fold Cross-Validation (KFCV). Just to be precise by repeated KFCV I mean the following:  I repeat the $K$ cross-validation on $R$ independent re-shuffles of the data set.

**Notation**

- $r=1,2,\ldots,R$  are the replicates
- $k=1,2,\ldots, K$ are folds (in each replicate)
- $\{L_k^{(r)}\}$ is the sequence of estimated loss, where $L_k^{(r)}$ is the loss computed on the $k$-th fold.

Let's arrange the output of the algorithm in a $K \times R$ matrix like this
$$
H = (L_k^{(r)}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
L_1^{(1)}  &  L_1^{(2)}  & \cdots & L_1^{(R)}\\
L_2^{(1)}  &  L_2^{(2)}  & \cdots & L_2^{(R)}\\
\vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
L_K^{(1)}  &  L_K^{(2)}  & \cdots & L_K^{(R)}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Estimated losses within the same column of $H$ are expected to be correlated, while elements along each row should not be correlated.

The estimated expected loss in the $r$-th replicate is given by 
$$
\bar L^{(r)} = \frac{1}{K} \sum_k L_k^{(r)},
$$
and this is an unbiased estimate of such expectation. However, the variance of $\bar L^{(r)}$ is inflated by the fact that the components of the sum  are correlated.  As far as I can understand, a  better approximation is to average across replicate:
$$
\hat{L} \; = \; \frac{1}{R} \sum_r \bar{L}^{(r)}
$$
This $\hat{L}$ is still unbiased, but its variance is smaller than that of $\bar L^{(r)}$  because it's an average of independent quantities.

What is not clear to me is how to approximates error bars around $\hat{L}$ that show up in any plot of the cross-validation output. It seems kind of strange, but I had to go through software source codes to see how these bars are produced, and I got mixed answers. I am a bit confused when talking about variance in cross-validation.

I'd like to be corrected if I am wrong. But an error bar about the estimated loss, in my opinion should be based on a confidence interval for the expected loss. Now one possible way is to come up with the "average +/- standard error" rule, which requires an estimate of the standard error.  The only think that makes sense to me is to compute the standard error of $\hat{L}$
$$
s^2=\frac{1}{R-1} \sum_r  \left(\bar L^{(r)} -  \hat{L} \right)^2,
$$

Based on this I would approximate the standard error se$(\hat{L})=s/\sqrt{R}$, and consider error bars such as $\hat{L} \; \pm$ se$(\hat{L})$.

Is this correct?